# Deploy Meteor App To AMAZON EC2 using MUP Error

Tags: node.js, meteor, amazon-ec2, meteor-up

I'm trying to use METEOR UP `MUP` to deploy my Meteor App to AWS AMAZON EC2.

I use different NPM Modules as well as METEOR PACKAGES in my Meteor App.  It all works perfectly on my computer.

When I do a `mup deploy` I get the following errors:

```
    [52.89.165.48] - Uploading bundle
[52.89.165.48] - Uploading bundle: SUCCESS
[52.89.165.48] - Setting up Environment Variables
[52.89.165.48] - Setting up Environment Variables: SUCCESS
[52.89.165.48] - Invoking deployment process
[52.89.165.48] x Invoking deployment process: FAILED

    -----------------------------------STDERR-----------------------------------
    sseph.h:4:0: warning: ignoring #pragma warning  [-Wunknown-pragmas]
     #pragma warning (disable : 4251)
     ^
    In file included from ../src/house.cc:1:0:
    ../src/swisseph.h:4:0: warning: ignoring #pragma warning  [-Wunknown-pragmas]
     #pragma warning (disable : 4251)
     ^
    In file included from ../src/eclipse.cc:1:0:
    ../src/swisseph.h:4:0: warning: ignoring #pragma warning  [-Wunknown-pragmas]
     #pragma warning (disable : 4251)
     ^
    gyp info ok 
    npm WARN package.json meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No description
    npm WARN package.json meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No repository field.
    npm WARN package.json meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No README data
    stop: Unknown instance: 
      % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                     Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 80: Connection refused
    App did not pick up! Please check app logs.
    -----------------------------------STDOUT-----------------------------------
    > node ./build.js

    `linux-x64-v8-3.14` exists; testing
    Binary is fine; exiting
    ansi-regex@0.2.1 node_modules/ansi-regex

    ansi-styles@1.1.0 node_modules/ansi-styles

    escape-string-regexp@1.0.3 node_modules/escape-string-regexp

    chalk@0.5.1 node_modules/chalk

    strip-ansi@0.3.0 node_modules/strip-ansi

    supports-color@0.2.0 node_modules/supports-color

    has-ansi@0.1.0 node_modules/has-ansi

    eachline@2.3.3 node_modules/eachline

    type-of@2.0.1 node_modules/type-of

    amdefine@1.0.0 node_modules/amdefine

    asap@2.0.3 node_modules/asap

    meteor-promise@0.4.8 node_modules/meteor-promise

    underscore@1.5.2 node_modules/underscore

    promise@7.0.4 node_modules/promise

    source-map-support@0.3.2 node_modules/source-map-support

    semver@4.1.0 node_modules/semver

    source-map@0.1.32 node_modules/source-map

    fibers@1.0.5 node_modules/fibers
    Waiting for MongoDB to initialize. (5 minutes)
    connected
    AppName start/running, process 12612
    Waiting for 15 seconds while app is booting up
    Checking is app booted or not?
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

What's causing this?
How do I solve this?

Thank you....it's my first time using AWS EC2...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your `mup.json` `nodeVersion` is up to date with the Node version (0.10.40) required by the latest Meteor version (1.2).

```
"nodeVersion": "0.10.40",
```

Comment: Wow! wasted almost 3 days on this error. Thanks @saimeunt.

Comment: Guess this is not in the documentation of the documentation

Comment: It's specified in the exhaustive Meteor 1.2 changelog : https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/History.md#other-bug-fixes-and-improvements